# Need Regular Expressions for

Tags: regex

I'm having lines in a text file like

```
<HintPath>..\..\..\..\lib\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
<HintPath>..\..\..\..\lib\New.Bksjdhf.Maintenance.STDTYU.dll</HintPath>
<HintPath>..\..\..\..\lib\New.Ware.Maintenance.STDFRT.dll</HintPath>
```

I need a regular expressions to output

EntityFramework

STDTYU

STDFRT

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: You don't need regex. First parse the input (looks like XML), then parse the paths and extract the filename. Strip the extension, and finally split the string on `.` and get the last one. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\w*(?=\.dll)
```

This one matches all letters before ".dll".

- So a string like this: `"Some.Name.Of.Assembly.dll"` will give `"Assembly"`
- A string like this: `"\..\..\Assembly.dll"` will also give `"Assembly"`

I usually test the expressions at http://regexstorm.net/tester

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to find the first occurrence of STD, then you select everything until and including the .dll extension. So use this:

`STD.+dll`

It depends on what you want to do, though. As @Niet the Dark Absol stated, it's probably preferable to just split your string instead of using regex.